# KendoUI-Grid Scrolling issue in IE 10 on Windows 8 tablet

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

KendoUI-Grid scrolling doesn't work in IE 10& 11 on a Windows 8 tablet. The swipe gestures for scrolling doesn't work. However The grid scrolling using gestures works in Google Chrome on the same windows 8 tablet.

Comment: did you find any solution?